# How to assign different Variable names while in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, format

```
class Card:
  def __init__(self, row, col):
    self.row = row
    self.col = col

for c in range(1,7):
    for r in range(1,7):
      Card_"row"-"col" = Card(r,c)
```

I want each card to be named based on its row and column. Ex. "Card_1-2" would be in row 1 and column 2, so that I can reference each card easier. Is there a way I can do that or is there a better way to look at the problem? Either way can someone please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables). What you are looking for is a dictionary. Naming variables will not make it easier, but accessing a dictionary will

Comment: `Card_1-2` isn't a valid variable name, even if this was a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary using cell coordinates is an easy solution in your case:

```
grid = {}
for r in range(1,7):
  for c in range(1,7):
    grid[r,c] = Card(r,c)
```

So each card may be later accessed by `grid[r,c]`

Comment: Thanks so much, this is probably what I'm going to use

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary that maps your desired name to each card.

```
from itertools import product
cards = {f"Card_{row}-{col}": Card(row, col) 
         for row, col in product(range(1,7), repeat=2)}
```